# Should images be stored on a subdomain or subdirectory?

Tags: subdomain, shared-hosting, directory

I'm working on a sharing app where images get stored for 24 hours. Does it bring any advantages to store them on a subdomain `http://imgs.example.com` instead of a subdirectory `http://www.example.com/imgs/`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storing them on a subdomain allows you to host them remotely simply by configuring DNS.  This can be a big advantage when you take things like geolocation into consideration.  These remote hosts may not be accessible to your web server via protocols that are required to host images in a subdirectory / virtual directory / etc.